# Parsing an element of variable type in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, types

I've finally managed to rig my Haskell program so that, at the very end, if I write

```
  let foo = bar :: A
```

then I get one behaviour, and if I write

```
  let foo = bar :: B
```

then I get the other desired behaviour.

Now I'd like my program to be able to parse this argument at runtime, but I really have no idea how to proceed. Any advice?

---

**Edit:** I'd like to parse some kind of (text) configuration file for which I am free to make up the specification/format.
One possible toy example is reading an integer as either an Int or a Double depending on further context provided in the configuration file, something along the lines of the following in the configuration file

```
barType: Int
barValue: 2
```

giving me bar = 2 :: Int, and

```
barType: Double
barValue: 2
```

giving me bar = 2 :: Double. Here it could be the case that I should be able to accept any type which has a Num instance.
In my case, I have a type class with some methods, and I'd like to parse anything with an instance for that type class; the methods could do something significantly different depending on the exact type. I don't know how I'd go about writing a Read instance for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to choose between types `A` and `B` based on run-time input?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  
I'm not able to just parse it into Either A B for instance, because I am not able to write the necessary instances needed for that type; moreover there are more than 2 types of interest, and I don't want to enumerate all the possibilities, rather I'd like to accept everything with the right type class.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this, I presume you have some code whose contents depend on the type of foo, but whose return type does not.  Suppose your full code example is

```
let foo = bar :: Int
in print (foo + 1)
```

Run-time parameter passing is normally accomplished by functions, so first rewrite the code as a function.  The `(Show a, Num a) =>` in the type signature shows that some type class methods are passed as a hidden parameter to the function.

```
printBar :: (Show a, Num a) => a -> IO ()
printBar x = print ((bar `asTypeOf` x) + 1)
```

For instance, `printBar (undefined :: Double)` will use type `Double` in its body.  The compiler finds that the argument has type `Double`, and it passes in the type class methods for `Double`.

Now, let's write a function that chooses the actual type of `printBar`.

```
invokeBar :: Bool -> (forall a. (Show a, Num a) => a -> b) -> b
invokeBar True  f = f (undefined :: Int)
invokeBar False f = f (undefined :: Double)
```

Now you can call `invokeBar True printBar` or `invokeBar False printBar` to choose whether to use `Int` or `Double`.

You cannot read in an "unknown type" from a file, because there is no file format encompassing *all* possible types.  However, you can make a parser that recognizes the names of the types you will use, and use the approach above for each of those names.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for different behaviors based on the type being instantiated, then you need a type class. Good examples to study would be [Data.Binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary/0.5.1.0/doc/html/src/Data-Binary.html#Binary) instances of even the `Read` type class.

E.g.

```
class Binary t where

    -- | Decode a value in the Get monad
    get :: Get t
```

You didn't say what kind of parsing you wanted to do -- text? binary? -- but it might be as simple as just reusing existing parsing libraries, and writing instances for your types.

Alternatively, you could use parser combinators to choose between different options.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really competent enough to properly understand what I'm meant to do from your answer. I added some specifics in the question that hopefully elucidate what I'm going for.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it the configuration file specifies how the parser further proceeds.  A very simple example of this is CSV, where the first line determines the number of fields in all following lines.  Assuming that all fields are string fields my variant would be to parse the first line into a parser that parses the following lines:

```
csvHeader :: Parser (Parser [String])
```

The result of `csvHeader` is a parser that is to be applied to all remaining lines:

```
csvHeader >>= many
```

Now in your case the actual result can also be one of many types.  The simplest way to do this is to have an ADT with the possible outcomes:

```
data CsvField = Coordinate Float Float | Person Name
```

A more advanced, safer and more flexible solution is not to think in terms of data, but in terms of the operations you can perform on them.  Say you are parsing a configuration file that contains a number, either an integer or a floating point number.  In either case you want to print the number to the screen.  So instead of returning the actual number, return the operation:

```
config :: Parser (IO ())
```

Finally if you want to keep some information about whatever is contained in the field while keeping the type variable, you need to become existential:

```
data Field = forall a. Field a (a -> a)
```

Now you can parse arbitrary things, as long as you return a value along with a function to apply to it:

```
config :: Parser Field
```

Comment: In your example here, I'd say that the `CsvField` ADT is by far the best approach. Any alternative that assumes you're performing some particular operation on the raw input (such as printing to the screen) is inherently *less* flexible than the ADT approach, which naturally decouples the data from the operations applicable to it.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example input:

```
barType: Int
barValue: 2
```

Since `barType` tells you how to interpret `barValue`, you need to either parse both lines in at the same time, or maintain state (using `State` or `StateT`) while parsing.  In either case, you basically need to pattern-match on the type.  For example, if I were using `Data.Binary.Get` for parsing, I'd have something like:

```
data Bar = IntBar Int | DoubleBar Double

parseBar :: String -> Get Bar
parseBar t = case t of 
  "Int" -> liftM IntBar $ get
  "Double" -> liftM DoubleBar $ get
```

Point being, no matter how you slice it, you need to know what types you'll be working with ahead of time, because your parser needs to account for them all. This also implies that a type class representing all the possible `Bar`-like things is probably not the way to go; you probably want a simple `Bar` ADT instead.

Comment: Well, I definitely do want a type class representing the possible Bar; that's how the rest of the program works. You are correct, however, that it doesn't seem to be a great fit for the parsing.

Is there no way I could do something like parseBar :: (exists a. Num a) => String -> a (avoiding the ADT) with similar code as above?